# How to convert Json to Array c#

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have been trying to convert Json response to C# Array and the thing is Json goes up from my head I dont understand its structure as its a mess for me.
here is the example response I have as Json

```
{
   "status":"ok",
   "urls":{
      "phone":[
         {
            "url":"tel:+9230154XXXXX",
            "uri":"+9230154XXXXX"
         }
      ],
      "sms":{
         "url":"sms:+9230154XXXXX",
         "uri":"+9230154XXXXX"
      },
      "vcf":"https:\/\/www.eac.com\/i2\/ajax\/item\/vcf\/"
   },
   "limitExceeded":false
}
```

Now all i want from this Json sms:+9230154XXXXX this value.
I am using Newtonsoft.Json in this example.
Bellow is what I have tried so far

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken jphone = jObject["urls"];
number = (string)jphone["phone"]["sms"];
```

Comment: Dont you have a class which matches your JSON? Serializing it will give you the required object easily

Comment: I dont have it.

Comment: I believe `string number = (string)jphone["sms"]["uri"];` is what you attempted

Comment: @derloopkat Life saver man! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Usage:**

```
jObject["urls"]["phone"].ToObject<PhoneEntry[]>()
```

**Class:**

```
public class PhoneEntry {
    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("uri")]
    public string Uri { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Fixed the little bug.

Answer (score 0):

I never really worked with Newtonsoft.Json but the following should work for you:

```
JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);
string number = (string)token.SelectToken("urls.sms.url")
```